# form submitting multiple times in IE depends on no.of click of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I am facing issue with IE, where form gets submitted that many no.of times, w.r.t the  no.of clicks of Submit button..
    Here is my flow..

```
  -> User enters the data in the form and upon click of submit button, will validate 
       the from
  -> if form data is valid, will open a bootstrap confirm request modal to show the data that was 
        entered and will provide another confirm submit button..when users clicks on 
        Confirm Submit button, will submit the form
```

Everything works fine so far, but when we close the confirm reqeust bootstrap modal and click on submit again and next click on Confirm Submit button on the modal now, the form was getting submitted twice..

so basically when we close the confirm request modal and redo the same process of submit again and again (means closing confirm reqeust modal and click on init submit button), then upon finally when we hit confrim submit button on the modal, then depending on the no.of clicks of submit button, the form was submitted that many no.of times...

```
** its happening only in IE**
```

my init submit button code:

```
<div class="form-group actionBtnGrp">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-form-action btn-primary-grey resetFormData">
                <spring:message code="cancel"></spring:message>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-form-action btn-primary-sub formSubmitBtn" id="saveBtn">
                <spring:message code="submit"></spring:message>
            </button>
        </div>
</div>
```

my confirm modal -  confrim submit button

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="subForm"class="btn btn-primary-sub">Confirm
            Request</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

my jquery submit code:

```
$("#policy-form").on('submit', function(event){
    var isvalidate=$('#policy-form').valid(); //calling validation method and doing validation
    if(isvalidate) {
        if(!$("#confirm-request").data('bs.modal') || $("#confirm-request").data('bs.modal').isShown != true) {  //checking confirm modal is open and opening
            $("#confirm-submit").modal('show');
            $('#subForm').text('Confirm Request')
              .prop('disabled', false);
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
        }
    }   
});
```

confrim request modal open and doing something and atlast will have confrim submit button to submit the request..

```
$('#confirm-request').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { // confirm request bootstrap modal
 ..//// doing something else 
   // finally submitting the request upon clicking confirm submit from 

$('#subForm').click(function () {
        $(this).text('Submitting ...')
          .prop('disabled', true);
        $('#policy-form').submit();  // submitting the form..
   });
```

as said, upon closing and reopening the bootstrap modal again and again, will submit the form that many times.(when we click on cofirm submit button...so does IE caching the no.of clicks of submit button and then submit that many no.of times..?)

anyhelp is really appreciated, as been struck on this since yesterday..

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an IE problem. It's a problem with your `click` binding. You are binding the `click` handler to the element inside the callback for `on`. Meaning you are binding a new handler each time you show the modal.

```
$('#confirm-request').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { // confirm request bootstrap modal
..//// doing something else 
// finally submitting the request upon clicking confirm submit from 

$('#subForm').click(function () {
    $(this).text('Submitting ...')
      .prop('disabled', true);
    $('#policy-form').submit();  // submitting the form..
});
```

Make it look like this

```
$('#subForm').click(function () {
    $(this).text('Submitting ...')
      .prop('disabled', true);
    $('#policy-form').submit();  // submitting the form..
});

$('#confirm-request').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { // confirm request bootstrap modal
..//// doing something else 
// finally submitting the request upon clicking confirm submit from
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @gforce301...i am not that pro in jquery/javascript..can u help me what i need to do in this case..!!

Comment: but i need to show the confirm request modal and after reviewing the data, he will click on confirm submit button which is on the modal and then submit the from..

Comment: I already put it in the answer. Remove the part that starts with `$('#subForm').click` and put it above the part that starts with `$('#confirm-request').on`

Comment: You're going to need to put more of the code up in your question where it can be read if you want me to help you with all that. I can only "imagine" so much.